# Is "recommend close" the same as casting a close vote?

Tags: discussion, support, review

I am relatively new to the website and just passed 2k reputation.  This has opened up more options for reviewing posts, particularly, the "low quality posts."  I've noticed that sometimes the option is to "delete" a post, whereas other times the option is to "recommend close."  While reading:  [What are the differences among "on hold", "closed" and "deleted" questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13840/what-are-the-differences-among-on-hold-closed-and-deleted-questions) I was led (by links in the first comment) to https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions which suggests that only users with 3k+ reputation can cast close votes.  I was just curious: if I "recommend close" is that "casting a close vote"? and if not, what does clicking "recommend close" actually result in?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [Review queues FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work):

> If you haven't earned the close privilege, you'll be offered a Recommend Close option instead - this carries no weight on its own, but puts the question in a queue for privileged users to confirm or decline.

So, *Recommend Close* adds the post to the Close queue without casting a close vote on it.

Comment: I can't believe I missed such an obvious source (sort of ashamed for having asked this question).  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Will a close recommendation be the same as flagging the post for closure, i.e. does it count as a disputed flag if the reviewers don't agree?

Comment: @DanielR It works like a flag would, but it shouldn't count as an actual flag, as far as I know. Look at your flag history to confirm.

Comment: Does it count as a flag in terms of "how many Looks OK/Keep Open reviews are needed to remove from queue"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't know. The _Recommended Close_ is an odd review function, which exists in the narrow range between 2K and 3K reputation. So it hasn't gotten much attention, and consequently documentation is poor. Besides, there is an ongoing push to remove questions from LQ review (it already happened on SO), keeping it for answers only.

Comment: Thanks. They should just open the queues at 10k and get it over with. :-P

Comment: @pizza I will have a look once (if ever) I get to 2k rep.