# Five close votes is not enough to close a question?

Tags: discussion, review, closing, low-quality-posts

I voted to close a question in [a Low Quality Post review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/978935).  There are more than five users who voted to close in the review, but why is it open?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not all users actually had the close privilege thus there were not five *votes* to close even though the review-ticket lists more than five reviews with that recommendation.

Likely this distinction should be made more clear on the ticket (as it is done for "delete" vs "recommend delete").

Comment: This was brought out in [Is "recommend close" the same as casting a close vote?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20319/is-recommend-close-the-same-as-casting-a-close-vote), but I'd not grasped the subtle point.